# Is there a way to make UserPrincipal.GetGroups() and UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups() calls use LDAPS (port 636) instead of LDAP (port 389)?

Tags: .net, active-directory, ldap, active-directory-group

We are preparing for Microsoft's March AD update to only allow secure calls using LDAPS, and while checking our .Net code, I discovered that calls to UserPrincipal.GetGroups() and UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups() appear to use LDAP (port 389) rather than LDAPS (port 636), even if the UserPrincipal object was created with a PrincipalContext established over LDAPS, like so:

```
    // Explicitly using LDAPS (port 636)
    PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "our.corpdomain.com:636", "DC=our,DC=corpdomain,DC=com", ContextOptions.Negotiate);
    UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, "someuser");

    // These calls still use LDAP (port 389)
    var groups = userPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups();
    var groups2 = userPrincipal.GetGroups();
```

Does anyone know why this might happen and, if so, how to force these calls to use LDAPS?  If they can't be forced, are there any workarounds for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly a bug in the .NET code, and I'll answer your question, but like I mentioned in your other question, the March update will not "only allow secure calls using LDAPS". The normal LDAP port of 389 will still work after that update. I've seen no evidence that they ever plan to disable it.

But if you want to ensure it never uses port 389 anyway, you will have no not use `UserPrincipal`. Use `DirectoryEntry` and/or `DirectorySearcher` directly, which is what `UserPrincipal` uses in the background anyway. This isn't [the first bug I've found](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/25887) in the `AccountManagement` namespace.

I wrote an article about [finding all of a user's groups](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/08/finding-all-of-a-users-groups.html), which has some sample code for different scenarios. You will have to modify any case where you create a new `DirectoryEntry` object and specify port 636, like this:

```
new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://example.com:636/CN=whatever,DC=example,DC=com")
```

You can actually omit the domain name if you want (just `:636` instead of `example.com:636`).

One case I didn't cover in that article is the equivalent to `GetAuthorizationGroups`, which is to read the `tokenGroups` attribute. That gives you a list of SIDs of the groups, which you can then look up to find the name of the group. Here is a method that will do that:

```cs
private static IEnumerable<string> GetTokenGroups(DirectoryEntry de) {
    var groupsFound = 0;

    //retrieve only the tokenGroups attribute from the user
    de.RefreshCache(new[] {"tokenGroups"});

    while (true) {
        var tokenGroups = de.Properties["tokenGroups"];
        foreach (byte[] groupSidByte in tokenGroups) {
            groupsFound++;
            var groupSid = new SecurityIdentifier(groupSidByte, 0);
            var groupDe = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://:{de.Options.PasswordPort}/<SID={groupSid}>");

            groupDe.RefreshCache(new[] {"cn"});
            yield return (string) groupDe.Properties["cn"].Value;
        }

        //AD only gives us 1000 or 1500 at a time (depending on the server version)
        //so if we've hit that, go see if there are more
        if (tokenGroups.Count != 1500 && tokenGroups.Count != 1000) break;

        try {
            de.RefreshCache(new[] {$"memberOf;range={groupsFound}-*"});
        } catch (COMException e) {
            if (e.ErrorCode == unchecked((int) 0x80072020)) break; //no more results

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

That will use whatever port you used for creating the `DirectoryEntry` object that you pass in. However, this breaks if you have more than one domain in your environment. Things can get complicated in that case if you want to always use port 636.

Comment: Thanks, Gabriel!  I tried the code, but it's not finding as many groups as GetAuthorizationGroups.  Trying to find a common thread.  The extra groups are all local, built-in groups (Everyone, Administrators, Performance Log Users, Authenticated Users, This Organization, Security asserted identity and High Mandatory Level).  I read your articles and I don't notice anything that might be the culprit.  We have one domain and no trusted external domains.  Any ideas?

Comment: The code I gave will only return AD group. Those groups you mention are not AD groups. They're either [well-known SIDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/81d92bba-d22b-4a8c-908a-554ab29148ab) (like `Everyone`) or local groups. Every account in existence will be considered part of `Everyone`. Local groups will change depending on the computer you run this code on. Is that something you actually need?

Comment: If you want to do this for the current user (the user that the code is running under), you can call [`WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.getcurrent?view=netframework-4.8#System_Security_Principal_WindowsIdentity_GetCurrent) and look at the [`Groups`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.groups) property.

Comment: What's odd is that your code returns "Users" which appears to be a well-known SID (S-1-5-32-545).  Actually, if you look at this [MS link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems) it lists each of these as either a group, an alias, an account or a built-in group.  Running `whoami /groups` shows the same thing.  I don't think we need these groups but I can't be sure.  The code I'm troubleshooting was built by someone else, and I just don't know enough about it or AD yet.

Comment: Unfortunately, the piece of code I'm troubleshooting does not use the current user, so I can't go with `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`.  BTW, I like your articles.  They are very informative!

Comment: Each domain does have a `Users` group with the exact same SID, so that's normal. It's in the `Builtin` container at the root of the domain (e.g. `CN=Users,CN=Builtin,DC=example,DC=com`)